# Android Recycler View caching

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using volley to load data using JSON Parsing in to a recycler view. I've used recylcer view before, but somehow, the downloaded data is persistent this time, meaning its still there after the app is closed, maybe stays in cache. I'm not sure, what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Edit: The application is storing downloaded data after the app is closed, which doesn't happen when using recycler view.

This is my Activity Class:

```
package com.example.recyclerview;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
 OnItemClick{

private ArrayList<PostData> posts = new ArrayList<>();

private PostRecycleViewAdapter viewAdapter;

private String listingJsonUrl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/";

Toolbar toolbar;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

    final RecyclerView.LayoutManager viewLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    viewAdapter = new PostRecycleViewAdapter(posts);
    final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(viewLayoutManager);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(viewAdapter);
    viewAdapter.setClickListener(this);

    new DownloadData().execute(listingJsonUrl);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view, int position) {
    final PostData data = posts.get(position);
    String title;
    int id;
    Intent commentIntent = new Intent(this, CommentsActivity.class);
    id = data.getId();
    title = data.getTitle();
    if(title.length() > 25){
        title = title.substring(0,25);
        title = title.concat("..");
    }
    commentIntent.putExtra("title",title) ;
    commentIntent.putExtra("id", id);
    startActivity(commentIntent);
}

class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url[0], new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        PostData postData = new PostData(jsonObject.getInt("id"),jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("body"));
                        posts.add(postData);
                        viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.d("JsonError", error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        getRequestQueue().add(jsonArrayRequest);
        return null;
    }
}

   public RequestQueue getRequestQueue()
{
    if (requestQueue == null)
    {
        requestQueue = com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }
    return requestQueue;
}


}
```

This is my RecyclerView Adapter Class:

```
package com.example.recyclerview;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;

public class PostRecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PostRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder>
{

 private List<PostData> postData;
 private OnItemClick itemClick;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    public TextView title, body;

    public ViewHolder(View view){
        super(view);
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        body = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.body);
        view.setTag(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(itemClick != null) itemClick.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition());

    }
}
public PostRecycleViewAdapter(List<PostData> postData)
{
    this.postData = postData;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.post_recycler_view,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemLayout);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PostRecycleViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    PostData data = postData.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(data.getTitle());
    holder.body.setText(data.getBody());

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return postData.size();
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);}

public void setClickListener(OnItemClick itemClick) {
    this.itemClick = itemClick;
}
}
```

And this is the data item class:

```
package com.example.recyclerview;


public class PostData {

private String title, body;
private int id;

public PostData(int id, String title, String body)
{
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getBody() {
    return body;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
}
```

Comment: Not clear , Explain it, and put your code